# fineOne object mongodb in nodejs returns strange object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, object

I am calling a document in MondoDB inside Nodejs. I am using fineOne method inside Nodejs and as I know findOne does not return a cursor and it just returns directly the document. This can be shown by printing normally the argument of the return function. But the problem is that when I use foreach method on the arguments I get many other object properties that looks like a cursor ( which is not as it does not have counter() method). I wanted to know why I get such extra keys if I use Object.keys() or even if I use for loop.

Thanks

As the summary:

I have the following object in my mongodb:

```
> db.test.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c37c2c59330361008a37ba0"),
        "uId" : ObjectId("5c37c28d9330361008a37b9f"),
        "tag" : true
}
```

When I find the object such in nodejs and using promises I see the following :

```
test.findOne({uId:my._id}).then(function(arg){
console.log(arg) // returns _id,uId and tag as I expect
Object.keys(arg).forEach(key => { console.log(key, arg[key]) }) //returns many strange things that behaves like a cursor
```

})

Output of the strange section :

```
$__ InternalCache {
  strictMode: true,
  selected: {},
  shardval: undefined,
  saveError: undefined,
  validationError: undefined,
  adhocPaths: undefined,
  removing: undefined,
  inserting: undefined,
  saving: undefined,
  version: undefined,
  getters: {},
  _id: 5c3c0ab365ceft76002c316u,
  populate: undefined,
  populated: undefined,
  wasPopulated: false,
  scope: undefined,
  activePaths:
     StateMachine {
     paths: { tag: 'init', _id: 'init', uId: 'init' },
     states:
      { ignore: {},
        default: {},
        init: [Object],
        modify: {},
        require: {} },
     stateNames: [ 'require', 'modify', 'init', 'default', 'ignore' ] },
  pathsToScopes: {},
  cachedRequired: {},
  session: undefined,
  ownerDocument: undefined,
  fullPath: undefined,
  emitter: EventEmitter { domain: null, _events: {}, _eventsCount: 0, _maxListeners: 0 },
  '$options': { skipId: true, isNew: false, willInit: true } }
isNew false
errors undefined
_doc { tag: true,
  _id: 5c3c0ab365ceft76002c316u,
  uID: 5c343225e44ce33343rgg616d }
$init true
```

Comment: Have you tried to examine second parameter ? Please take a look here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne

Comment: Hello micki, Yes if I have the second parameters it will be OK but I do not want to make the second parameter  as projection because I want to have the same function to call different documents which have different fields each

Comment: I mean `.then(function(err, arg)`

Comment: It gives me error actually. It just accept one argument which contains the objects which I guess because of using Promises ( .then().catch() chain)

Comment: When not passing a callback function to `findOne()` is will return a Promise that either rejects with error or resolves with the document. `.then(function(err, arg)` is not valid, because there will never be two arguments. Any errors will be passed as a promise rejection, not as a parameter to the resolve function.

Comment: In your case, because you're using Mongoose, the return value of a `.findOne()` is actually a `Query` instance (which is also `thenable`). Upon evaluating the `.then()` of the `Query` instance, you will get an object, but it's not a plain javascript Object, rather a `Model` instance as defined in Mongoose. That is the reason for which your inspection of its keys gives all the _hidden_ internal properties as well.

Comment: Thanks Mihai. Is there a simple way to just get the main keys instead of the hidden one? I am using two forEach inside each other to solve it but it is a bit awkward to do it. Thanks